# How to use my own Classes in JSP and is this a good way of doing it?

Tags: java, class, jsp, import

I have class `Project.java` and want to use it inside `home.jsp`

This is my directory structure, I tried putting the class file in  my project root folder as well as classes folder ... 
How do I import it and use it my jsp...What I try below doesnt work

[image]

When I include the import statement the JSP shows a blank page ..without it ,it works.

PS:How to debug JSPs when something goes wrong I get a blank page...no error message ...its not useful to find out what went wrong

Answer (score 2):

Some notes on that:

- your classes are in the root/default  package.
- they're perfectly fine in WEB-INF/classes
- no import needed for classes from root/default package
- Scriplets are very old. Check out JSTL
- Once you put your classes in packages (which I recommend), you'll need to import them

About the debug:

Check the server log. There should be some exception there.

Comment: I did , I removed the import and added just this   `<% Project p %>` , JSP goes blank again :(

Comment: Project p; just declares reference ...why is it invalid?

Comment: So what does the server complain about? Define not working. Maybe edit your question and add current code?